# Selenium Web Driver to click button in Eclipse IDE

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Is it possible to use Selenium Web Driver to bring up IDE, and click some button in IDE?

I have a website, and if I click a button in the website, it does some stuff in Eclipse IDE.

The thing is, Selenium Web Driver only works for Web stuff, but are there any ways to interact Selenium and Eclipse IDE?

Comment: You answered your own question: "Selenium Web Driver only works for Web stuff". So the answer is: no!

Comment: Looking for sth else. I thought there is a way to combine tools to make it work.

Comment: That is a different question. Perhaps have a read through [ask] first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org/) which is a tool developed by MIT and CUBoulder.

It kind of automate the process based on virtual features and might help you move forward a bit.

Here is a [helloworld](http://doc.sikuli.org/tutorials/helloworld/helloworld-mac.html) example that shows you how the tool works.